# Grep multiple strings after curl -s

Tags: bash, curl, scripting, grep

I'm trying to write a bash script where I give a few variables as such:

```
var1="text1"
var2="text2"
var3="text3"
var4="text4"
var5="text5"
var6="text6"
```

I've tried it with one variable and the following script works fine:

```
if curl -s "https://web.net/list.txt" | grep $var1
echo $var1 is on the list
else
echo "FFHGFHFGHFHFG"
fi
```

I've been trying to input the other variables, which are hardcoded as those are not going to change, like this:

```
if curl -s "https://web.net/list.txt" | grep "$var1\|$var2"

if curl -s "https://web.net/list.txt" | grep '$var1|$var2'
```

I cannot remember all of the ways I've tried to do this, but that is my current attempt.

The idea is to find those values in a given site, output those values if the exist and nothing else.

Comment: What's the issue? `grep "$var1\|$var2"` doesn't display anything?

Comment: No it doesn't. I can't figure it out.

Comment: WIth a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like `VAR1='Example'; VAR2='Domain'; if curl --silent https://www.example.com | grep "$VAR1\|$VAR2"; then echo "On the list"; fi` I am not able to reproduce an issue.

Comment: Are you sure `curl` outputs the content of `$var1` or `$var2`?

Comment: Oh no, I'm trying to get info hosted on a site in the format of file.txt. What I'm trying to grep are keywords from that file. Using 1 variable the thing works fine; as soon as I input a 2dn. variable, that's when the program exits with no output at all.

Comment: Small example: `var1=head;var2=body;curl -s http://free.fr | grep "$var1\|$var2"` does output something.

Comment: is `grep -e "$var1" -e "$var2"` etc etc... not sufficient?

Comment: Whether or not the `|` needs to be escaped depends on whether your version of `grep` is using basic or extended regular expressions. In either case, you need to use `"..."` instead of `'...'` so that `grep` sees the *value* of the two variables, rather than the literal strings `$var1` and `$var2`.

Comment: Using this curl -s "https://website.net/file.txt" | grep "$var1\|$var2" isn't working. Using grep "f\|i" finds only the letter i. Using grep "f"\|"i"; grep "f|i"; grep -e "f"\|"i" finds neither.

Comment: Since within the comments were provided independently two working minimal examples, what is the result if you just copy and paste and execute them?

Comment: Yes, it was solved, somehow this worked: var1=head;var2=body;curl -s http://free.fr | grep "$var1\|$var2".  Thanks a lot for all you help! :) You are all most kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
var1=head;var2=body;curl -s http://free.fr | grep "$var1\|$var2"
```

Ended up doing this:

```
var1=something1;var2=something2;var3=something3;var4=something4;var5=something5;var6=something6;
```

Code runs

```
var1=something1;var2=something2;var3=something3;var4=something4;var5=something5;var6=something6;
if curl -s https://website.net/text.txt | grep "$var1\|$var2\|$var3\|$var4\|$var5\|$var6" 
then
echo $var1 
echo $var2
else (...)
```

and so on.

After that I'm sending the results to a file for further analysis.

Thanks all.

Comment: Consider using `grep -E` to enable ERE-format regexes so you don't need to backslash-escape the `|` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide multiple patterns to `grep` and it will return successfully if any of them matches:

```
if curl -s 'https://web.net/list.txt' | grep -e "$var1" -e "$var2" -e "$var3" -e "etc."; then
  echo "Contains $var1 or $var2 or $var3 or ..."
fi
```

Doing it this way also allows you to specify `-F` to match only on fixed strings. This helps to prevent issues if your variables contain meta characters such as `*` or `.`.